# The difference in defining PI in C

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in programming and I have a question. Mainly, what is the difference in defining PI exactly as I state below;

```
#define PI  (4.*atan(1))
#define PIa  4.*atan(1)
#define PIb  4*atan(1)
```

I have printed this code:

```
    printf( "%lf\n", 3 / PI );
    printf( "%lf\n", 3 / PIa );
    printf( "%lf\n", 3 / PIb );
```

The results are:

```
 0.954930
 0.589049
 0.000000
```

According to my calculator the first one is correct, and the rest should also be.
Why aren't they?

Comment: The difference is in the literal expansion of the macros. `3 / PIb` will become `3 / 4*atan(1)` - and here the first operation is *integer division* `3/4`, which is giving `0`. In `3 / PIa` the expansion leads to division to be carried out first too, which is not the correct order of operations.

Comment: I would include math.h and use `M_PI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro is text substitution thus:

```
3 / PIa
```

is parsed as:

```
3 / 4.*atan(1) = (3/4.) * atan(1)
```

This is different from the first case where `3 / PI` is expanded as:

```
3 / (4.*atan(1))
```

The similar case is for the third example:

```
3 / 4*atan(1) = (3/4) * atan(1)
```

The expression `3/4` is integer division, which result is `0`.

Generally, it is strongly advised to put parentheses around the whole macro and all parameters it takes like in the following example:

```
#define ADD(a,b) ((a) + (b))
```

Comment: Macro replacement substitutes preprocessor tokens, not text. Otherwise `#define x -a` could make `b-x` into `b` `--` `a` instead of `b` `-` `-` `a`.

Comment: I get it now, thank you! :)